# Accessing a view from within the in recyclerview adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a simple activity set up like

```
 ConstraintLayout
     LinearLayout
         TextView1
         RecyclerView containing TextView2
         TextView3
```

The recyclerview is just a list of answers. In the onBindViewHolder, I have an onClick that changes TextView2 either green or red. I would also like to setVisability on TextView3 to VISIBLE when clicked. 
In the onclick I added

```
 textView3 = v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
 textView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

The setVisibilty method returns a null object reference for textView3. Is it possible to manipulate TextView3 which is outside of the recyclerview from within the recyclerview adapter?

Comment: Have you tried passing the TextView3 as a reference to the RecyclerviewConstructor, and then modifying the reference?

Comment: Thank you!! that worked and now I have a better understanding of whats going on